# how to implement conditional htmlspecialchars?

Tags: php, html, escaping

If it's `<script src="/script/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript">` ,should call `htmlspecialchars`.

If it's `<pre><code><script src="/script/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></code></pre>`,should leave it as is.

How to do this kind of task?

**EDIT**

Think you are using wmd editor like SO,and you included some code but didn't format it,in this case it should be processed by htmlspecialchars,but if you formatted it as "Code Sample",there is no need to process

Comment: I think you want them the other way round. There's no need to place `<script>` within a `<pre>` if you want to execute the JS, if, however, you want show the `<script>` tag when it is within `<pre>` you'll need to HTML escape it with `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: Where are these two situations occurring? Why do you sometimes have it without the `<pre>`, and why do you want different behaviour each time? You don't make it clear whether you're trying to display the code or execute the JS.

Answer (score 0):

I would make two scripts: jquery.autocomplete.js, and jquery.autocomplete.pre.js. In the latter, don't call htmlspecialchars.

Comment: How to make it programmatical?I don't know which case it is in code.